# Is it possible to Embed a PDF as HTML in an email?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically i have a PDF and either want to frame it or convert it to HTML and display it within an email. I haven't found a working solution.

The following is an example that i am looking for, this works in a browser, but not email. Thanks

```
<object data="MyPDF.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. Quite simple way - you can convert pdf to images (one per page) and place all in email's html body. Its not as useful as plain text and usually much bigger than pdf itself. You can also convert to html using ocr software.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any reasonable way to convert a PDF to HTML unless you have the source from which the PDF was generated (assuming it's generated).

Your best bet is to include it as a separate attachment. You could try to inline it but the results will be highly client-dependent (e.g. *<object />* might work for Outlook but certainly not any other client).